# If we say "Frankfurt am Main" why do we have "Frankfurt an der Oder"?

Tags: difference, grammatical-case

What's the difference here - why we use **am** in one example, and **an der** in the other?

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/gender-of-german-rivers

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/genus-der-fl%C3%BCsse-eine-komische-regel

Comment: You are wondering why Main is a guy, and Oder is a maid? Well, many people scratch their heads too...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gender of German rivers?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/gender-of-german-rivers)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is because Main is masculine, while Oder is feminine.

Then, *an* in this meaning is locative (where is it?), so one should use dative.

Therefore:

*Frankfurt am Main = Frankfurt an dem Main* (because *der Main*)

*Frankfurt an der Oder* (because *die Oder*)

Comment: Thanks! The "an dem" to "am" part was a bit confusing at first :)

Comment: It is worth to mention, that for *an der* no condensed form exists, see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43776/1696). Therefore the variants look more different than they could in case of regularity.

Comment: Dialect often has *ana*.

Comment: I've never seen "ana" in written form. I tend to believe that it is just a slurred form of "an der" and not actually a condensed word.

Comment: @Janka If you really want to write this, it would be "an 'er".

Comment: Or written as one word (since it's a contraction): "anner"

Comment: If "`The "an dem" to "am" part was a bit confusing at first`", look out for others, such as `beim` (`bei dem`). Every language that I know has contractions, and you will find some in German too.

Answer (score 26):

Because in German river names have various genders. Some rivers a masculine, some are femine. So it is

> der Main

but

> die Oder

and thus "*am Main*" (= an dem Main) but "*an der Oder*".

Comment: Question then: Are rivers mostly feminine or mostly masculine? Is there ever a neuter river?

Comment: They are mostly feminine: Die Elbe, die Wolga, die Donau.

But exceptions: der Rhein, der Main, der Neckar

Comment: @Wilson According to [this article](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/fragen-an-den-zwiebelfisch-warum-ist-der-rhein-maennlich-und-die-elbe-weiblich-a-364172.html) there are 72 rivers with a length of 100 km or more in Germany, and only 8 are masculine: der Rhein, Main, Inn, Neckar, Lech, Kocher, Regen, Rhin. And I don't know a neuter river.

Comment: On the other hand, non-European rivers seem generally to be masculine: der Nil, der Ganges, der Amazonas, der Mississippi, der Jordan, der Euphrat, …

Comment: French has "la rivière" (feminine) and "le fleuve" (masculine).  A "fleuve" is a major river that (nearly always) flows into the sea/ocean.  A "rivière" is a more minor river.  So, in Canada (where I come from), the St. Lawrence river is "Le St-Laurent", while the St. Maurice river (which flows into the St. Lawrence) is "La St-Maurice".  I'm assuming that the rule in Germany is similar

Comment: @Flydog57 The french rule does not really apply in German: of the 8 masculine german rivers mentioned by IQV only one (Rhein) is flowing directly into the sea, all others flow into other rivers. ("Rhin" is obviously derived from "Rhein", and all the others are in southern Germany, which might be related.) The other big rivers (Elbe, Donau, Oder) are all female.

Comment: *Der St.-Lorenz-Strom* is masculine in German, too, because it's *der Strom* (the stream) included in the name. The only rule I could make out is about names ending in consonants or -o (der Rhein, der Jordan, der Nil, der Ob, der Kongo, der Po, der Ebro, der Tejo), these tend to be male. Counterexample: die Oder. But maybe this is because -er is a vowel in German.

Comment: About river genders there is a great anser [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/genus-der-fl%C3%BCsse-eine-komische-regel) . Unfortunately it is in german.

Comment: When I was in high school I was taught the rule of thumb that Rhein and its tributaries are masculine and the rest of them are feminine. Main flows into Rhein, hence masculine. IIRC the scope of that (undoubtedly sweeping) statement was *rivers in Germany*. I'm prepared to be wrong.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Inn, Lech and Regen flow into Donau (danube). It has more to do with the celtic origin of the names.

Comment: Thanks. Wonder where that rule of thumb came from :-)

Answer (score 1):

The declination of "der" and "die" in the case of a Dative case.
"An der" and "Am" are actually Dative (location).
"Am" is, as other mentioned, a composition of "An dem"

So in the masculine case,
the Dative of "der" is "dem"
and in the feminine case,
the Dative of "die" is "der" (which is the same article as the masculine nominative)

Sorry, confusing but just the way it is.

[image: Dative articles]